# %debug magic command not working in the Q# Jupyter Notebook environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic, q#

As per the documentation provided by Microsoft Azure Quantum at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-command-line-qdk) , I followed the steps given and installed Q# with Jupyter Notebook, using Anaconda.

I then wrote the following Q# program in a Jupyter Notebook (IQ# kernel) using the code taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/testing-debugging?tabs=tabid-vs2022).

(I am currently using Google Chrome)

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;

operation MultiQubitDumpMachineDemo() : Unit {
       
       use qubit = Qubit();
       
       H(qubit);
       
       DumpMachine();
       
       Reset(qubit);

   }
```

When I used the magic commands such as %simulate and %trace, the program executed normally. The DumpMachine result clearly shows the qubit in a superposition of |0> and |1> (measurement probability is 50%), and the trace command printed out the quantum circuit.

[%simulate Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaeT1.png)

[%trace Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSPcA.png)

However, when I run the %debug command, **the interactive HTML display does not work**. The debug control button can display the circuit but, the controls for the chart options do not display the amplitudes, probabilities, or real/imaginary co-efficients.

When I opened the console, I observed the following error, every time I clicked the chart options controls:

```
Couldn't process kernel message TypeError: state.getDenseAmplitudes is not a function
    at fitChart (bundle.js?v=20221015232727:292:32)
    at Object.updateChart (bundle.js?v=20221015232727:277:9)
    at update (bundle.js?v=20221015232727:811:32)
    at bundle.js?v=20221015232727:850:17
    at Kernel._handle_iopub_message (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:63064:20)
    at Kernel._finish_ws_message (main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:62843:29)
    at main.min.js?v=a4e125c812cb3975203ae429a5b40d180b59b8e4602fcc78390ef4f0dd4d14ac3559189f65f23cd50fd971f98f5842b7746f4182babd20b7ca84e52314bcd4ac:62834:44
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeYs6.png)

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this type of error or its possible solutions, so I didn't try anything more than updating the 'iqsharp' package.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error, and, if possible, provide with me a solution for the same?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a bug - can you please file it at https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mariia Mykhailova. I will file the issue on Github.